# Vagrant: The following settings shouldn't exist: ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Hello and thanks for taking the time to look into this issue with me. I have recently transitioned to a new workstation and have discovered that my Vagrantfile is not working. If it matters, the workstation is new but the operating system (RHEL 7.4) remains the same. Same versions of Vagrant (2.0.1) and VirtualBox (5.2)

The error I am receiving when executing `vagrant up`:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: ssh
```

Below is the Vagrantfile, it's worth mentioning that I can get the first device (aggregation01) to boot successfully if I comment out the string `aggregation01.vm.ssh.insert_key = false`, but this workaround is not consistent when applying to my other boxes.

Only showing the first ~80 lines of the Vagrantfile due to brevity, full file can be viewed at [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/packetferret/vagrant_network_multivendor_access/blob/master/Vagrantfile)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Spine-Leaf Architecture in a Multi-vendor Campus Access layer
#
#
#                           +---------------+         +---------------+
#                           | aggregation01 |         | aggregation02 |
#                           +---------------+         +---------------+
#                              |              \     /            |
#                              |                \ /              |
#                              |                / \              |
#                              |              /     \            |
#                           +---------------+         +---------------+
#                           |    spine01    |         |    spine02    |
#                           +---------------+         +---------------+
#                           /  |      \       \      /        /  |  \
#                       /      |         \      / \       /      |     \
#                   /          |          / \         /\         |        \
#               /              |     /         \  /         \    |           \
#           /                  |/            /     \            \|              \
#       /                  /   |         /            \          |   \             \
#   /                 /        |     /                   \       |         \          \
#   +--------------+        +---------------+         +---------------+        +--------------+
#   |    leaf01    |        |    leaf02     |         |    leaf03     |        |    leaf04    |
#   +--------------+        +---------------+         +---------------+        +--------------+

arista = 'arista_vEOS_4_20'
junos_pfe = 'juniper/vqfx10k-pfe'
junos = 'juniper/vqfx10k-re'
cumulus = 'CumulusCommunity/cumulus-vx'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  # ######################################
  # ###   Define namespace for boxes   ###
  # ######################################
  # sp1 = "spine01"
  # sp2 = "spine02"
  # agg1 = "aggregation01"
  # agg2 = "aggregation02"
  # leaf01 = "leaf01"
  # leaf01_pfe = "leaf01_pfe"
  # leaf02 = "leaf02"
  # leaf02_pfe = "leaf02_pfe"
  # leaf03 = "leaf03"
  # leaf03_pfe = "leaf03_pfe"
  # leaf04 = "leaf04"
  # leaf04_pfe = "leaf04_pfe"
  wbid = ENV['USER']
  offset = 0

  # ######################################
  # ###    aggregation01 - build vm    ###
  # ######################################
  config.vm.define "aggregation01" do |aggregation01|
    aggregation01.vm.ssh.insert_key = false
    aggregation01.vm.hostname = "aggregation01"
    aggregation01.vm.box = cumulus
    aggregation01.vm.box_version = "3.5.0"
    aggregation01.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "#{wbid}_aggregation01"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, '--audiocontroller', 'AC97', '--audio', 'Null']
      v.memory = 768
    end
    #   see note here: https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt#synced-folders
    aggregation01.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    # NETWORK INTERFACES
    # link for swp1 --> spine01
    aggregation01.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "aggregation01_spine01", auto_config: false , :mac => "a00000000161"
    # link for swp2 --> spine02
aggregation01.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "aggregation01_spine02", auto_config: false , :mac => "443839000143"
    # link for swp3 --> tbd
aggregation01.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: "aggregation01_aggregation02", auto_config: false , :mac => "44383900014c"
    aggregation01.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox|
      vbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nicpromisc2', 'allow-all']
      vbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nicpromisc3', 'allow-all']
      vbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nicpromisc4', 'allow-all']
      vbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
    end
    # Fixes "stdin: is not a tty" and "mesg: ttyname failed : Inappropriate ioctl for device"  messages --> https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1673
    aggregation01.vm.provision :shell , inline: "(sudo grep -q 'mesg n' /root/.profile 2>/dev/null && sudo sed -i '/mesg n/d' /root/.profile  2>/dev/null) || true;", privileged: false
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simply dropping the `.vm` from the line might remove the error, such that

```
aggregation01.vm.ssh.insert_key = false
```

should be

```
aggregation01.ssh.insert_key = false
```

And likewise for the other VMs. But it looks like you've maybe already resolved this in the git repository because the ssh lines are different there?

I tried recreating the first two VMs based on the vagrantfile in the repository and managed to do it without error but when I re-entered the `.vm` in the line I got the same error you are getting.